# С# Повисают формы при закрытии потоков

Tags: c#

Проблема состоит собственно в том, что форма повисает, когда я закрываю потоки, в которых эта форма не открыта.

Вход в форму осуществляется через события `StartServer()` и `StartClient(...)`.

Вот собственно сама форма:

```
private void Chat_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    cli.StopClient();
    serv.StopServer();
    string msg = "Server and Client shutdowned" + Environment.NewLine
            + "Is Server Working = " + serv.IsServerRunning.ToString() + Environment.NewLine
            + "Is Client Working = " + cli.IsClientRunning.ToString();
    MessageBox.Show(msg);
}
```

Вот события запускающие потоки( StartClient() и StartServer())

```
public void StartServer()
{
    IsServerRunning = true;
    IpServ = IPAddress.Parse(StrIpServ);
    serv = new Thread(new ThreadStart(DoServer));
    serv.Start();
    ClientManager = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ClientsManager));
    ClientManager.Start();
}
public void StartClient()
{
    IsClientRunning = true;
    IPAddress IpAddr = RealIp;
    CliSocket = new Socket(IpAddr.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
    CliSocket.Connect(RealIp, port);
    sending = new Thread(new ThreadStart(sender));
    sending.Start();
    Thread.Sleep(100);
    listen = new Thread(new ThreadStart(listener));
    listen.Start();
}
```

И вот события завершающие работу сервера и клиента

```
public void StopServer()
{
    IsServerRunning = false;
    Thread.Sleep(100);
    foreach (Socket cli in Clients)
    {
        cli.Disconnect(false);
    }
    Thread.Sleep(100);
    if (serv.IsAlive)
    {
        serv.Abort();
    }
    if (ClientManager.IsAlive)
    {
        ClientManager.Abort();
    }
}
public void StopClient()
{
    IsClientRunning = false;
    Thread.Sleep(100);
    CliSocket.Disconnect(false);
    Thread.Sleep(100);
    if (listen.IsAlive)
    {
        listen.Abort();
    }
    if (sending.IsAlive)
    {
        sending.Abort();
    }
}
```

Если же заменить `....Abort()` на `....Suspend()`, то форма не будет повисать, однако при закрытии всех форм отладка будет продолжаться, будто происходят еще какие-то вычисления.

Класс клиента:

```
class Client
{
    public int MessageSize = 4096;
    public Boolean IsClientRunning = false;
    public int port = 7777;
    public int CliPort = 7776;
    public int backlog = 15;
    Mutex mut = new Mutex(); 
    public IPAddress RealIp;
    Socket CliSocket;
    Thread sending;
    Thread listen;
    public List<String> Messages = new List<String>();
    public List<String> SendBuffer = new List<String>();
    public void StartClient()
    {
        IsClientRunning = true;
        IPAddress IpAddr = RealIp;
        CliSocket = new Socket(IpAddr.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        CliSocket.Connect(RealIp, port);
        sending = new Thread(new ThreadStart(sender));
        sending.Start();
        Thread.Sleep(100);
        listen = new Thread(new ThreadStart(listener));
        listen.Start();
    }
    private void listener()
    {            
        while (IsClientRunning)
        {
            try
            {
                byte[] bytes = new byte[MessageSize];
                CliSocket.Receive(bytes);                   
                if (!IsEmptyMsg(bytes))
                {
                    string str = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(bytes);
                    string str1 = TrimNull(str);
                    str1.Trim();
                    mut.WaitOne();
                    Messages.Add(str1);
                    mut.ReleaseMutex();
                }                    
                Thread.Sleep(0);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw e;
            }
        }
    }
    private void sender()
    {
        try
            {
                while (IsClientRunning)
                {
                    mut.WaitOne();
                    if (SendBuffer.Count > 0)
                    {
                        for(int i =0; i<SendBuffer.Count;i++)
                        {
                            string msg = SendBuffer[i];
                            byte[] bytes = new byte[MessageSize];
                            bytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(msg);
                            CliSocket.Send(bytes);
                            Messages.Add(msg);
                            SendBuffer.Remove(msg);
                        }
                    }
                    mut.ReleaseMutex();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
            throw e;
            }
    }
```

Класс сервера:

```
class Server
{
    public int port = 7777;
    public Boolean IsServerRunning = false;
    public List<Socket> Clients = new List<Socket>();
    public int MessageSize = 4096;
    Mutex mut = new Mutex();
    public string StrIpServ = "127.0.0.1";
    public int backlog = 15;
    private IPAddress IpServ;
    Thread ClientManager;
    Thread serv;
    public void StartServer()
    {
        IsServerRunning = true;
        IpServ = IPAddress.Parse(StrIpServ);
        serv = new Thread(new ThreadStart(DoServer));
        serv.Start();
        ClientManager = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ClientsManager));
        ClientManager.Start();
    }
    public void DoServer()
    {
        IPEndPoint LocalEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IpServ, port);
        Socket ConnectReceiver = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        ConnectReceiver.Bind(LocalEndPoint);
        ConnectReceiver.Listen(backlog);
        while (IsServerRunning)
        {
            try
            {
                mut.WaitOne();
                Socket Cli = ConnectReceiver.Accept();
                if (Cli.Connected)
                {
                    Clients.Add(Cli);
                }
                mut.ReleaseMutex();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw e;
            }
        }        
    }
    private void ClientsManager()
    {
        while (IsServerRunning)
        {
            try
            {
                mut.WaitOne();
                if (Clients.Count > 0)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < Clients.Count; i++)
                    {
                        Socket cli = Clients[i];
                        byte[] bytes = new byte[MessageSize];
                        cli.Receive(bytes);
                        if (!IsEmptyMsg(bytes))
                        {
                            MsgSender(bytes, cli);
                        }
                    }

                }
                mut.ReleaseMutex();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw e;
            }
        }
    }       

    private void MsgSender(byte[] bytes,Socket NoSend)
    {
        mut.WaitOne();
        foreach (Socket cli in Clients)
        {

            try
            {
                if (cli != NoSend)
                {
                    Socket sender = cli;
                    sender.Send(bytes);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw e;
            }
        }
        mut.ReleaseMutex();
    }
```

Comment: Для начала, никогда не используйте `Thread.Abort` и `Thread.Suspend`. Это известный прямой путь к дедлокам.

Comment: Затем, не поленитесь выкинуть из кода в вашем вопросе всё, что не относится к проблеме. Чем меньше будет ваш пример, тем больше шансов, что квалифицированному участнику захочется в нём разобраться.

Comment: @VladD А как же тогда следует закрывать треды?

Comment: А они должны сами себя закрыть, когда вам нужно. Наладьте коммуникацию с ними, пошлите сигнал закрыться. Только так, другого пути нет.

Comment: А что происходит в самих потоках?

Comment: @VladD не очень понимаю, что вы имеете ввиду. Просто, когда я закрываю программу в режиме отладки, режим отладки не закрывается, будто что-то еще происходит. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: @VladD там работают сокеты на отправку и прием данных

Comment: Ну, как потоку закрыть самому себя, надеюсь, понятно? (Если нет: выполнить команду `return` из своей функции.) Теперь, вам нужно, чтобы код потока узнал, что ему надо закрыться.

Comment: А как этот код общается с остальной частью программы? Вот пришли данные, куда они складываются?

Comment: @VladD я создал глобальные переменные, через них потоки и общаются. Могу добавить код классов сервера и клиента в вопрос, если нужно.

Comment: Весь код не стоит, лучше только необходимый минимум. А доступ к глобальным переменным защищён мьютексом?

Comment: @VladD я только начал программировать, поэтому не знаю, что такое мьютекст. Сейчас добавлю.

Comment: @VladD добавил, как вы и просили.

Comment: Ох. Обязательно почитайте. Это как бы азы многопоточного программирования. Подумайте, что будет, если два потока будут одновременно обращаться к одним и тем же данным.

Comment: @VladD Вы правы, сейчас добавлю в код, однако решит ли это проблему "когда я закрываю программу в режиме отладки, режим отладки не закрывается, будто что-то еще происходит"

Comment: @VladD, добавил в код мьютекс. Однако проблему это не решило.

Comment: Возможно, проблема в том, что вы прерываете `Socket.Receive`. Мьютекс решает не эту проблему, он решает проблему одновременного доступа к данным из двух различных потоков..

Comment: @VladD Даже если не прерывать ничего, эта проблема остается. Да и процесс остается.

Comment: @max619: адЪ. Зачем создавать потоки вручную? Почему нельзя использовать async или хотя бы APM? (вопрос про смысл в написании клиент-сервера на сокетах пропущу, как риторический).

Comment: @Dennis, я только начинаю программировать, поэтому и не знаю как практичнее орагнизовать клиент-сервер. Также я не знаю как пользоваться async методами. Тем не менее, я не могу понять почему собственно не закрывается процесс после закрытия приложения. я добавил в `Program.cs` новый метод 
`public void Exit()
        {
            Application.Exit();
        }
`
это не помогло(
который вызываю при `Form1_FormClosing`

Comment: @Dennis, тоесть вы считаете, что из-за того, что я пользуюсь реализацией с помощью потоков приложение и не закрывается?

Comment: Я считаю, что это замусоривает код, и понять причину проблемы сложнее, и, кроме того, изначально нехорошо. Думаю, что рациональнее потратить силы на изучение async/await, чем на поиск дедлоков в этом коде.

Answer (score 1):

Если задать потоку свойство [`IsBackground`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.threading.thread.isbackground(v=vs.110).aspx), то он автоматически завершиться при завершении основного потока. Если у вас проблема только в остановке всех потоков и вы не хотите менять архитектуру, то можно по всей программе проставить это свойство перед созданием потоков. Например:

```
//Сервер:
public void StartClient()
{
    IsClientRunning = true;
    IPAddress IpAddr = RealIp;
    CliSocket = new Socket(IpAddr.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
    CliSocket.Connect(RealIp, port);
    sending = new Thread(new ThreadStart(sender));
    sending.IsBackground = true;
    sending.Start();
    Thread.Sleep(100);
    listen = new Thread(new ThreadStart(listener));
    listen.IsBackground = true;
    listen.Start();
}

//Клиент:

public void StartServer()
{
    IsServerRunning = true;
    IpServ = IPAddress.Parse(StrIpServ);
    serv = new Thread(new ThreadStart(DoServer));
    serv.IsBackground = true;
    serv.Start();
    ClientManager = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ClientsManager));
    ClientManager.IsBackground = true;
    ClientManager.Start();
}
```

Comment: _"Если задать потоку свойство IsBackground, то он автоматически завершиться при завершении основного потока."_ -- не завершается. проверял так: `new Thread(() => { new Thread(() => { int i = 5; while (i-- > 0) { Thread.Sleep(1000); Console.Write(i); } }) { IsBackground = true }.Start(); Thread.Sleep(3000); Console.WriteLine("|"); }).Start();` -- выводит: 43|210.

Comment: @Stack          Не правильно проверяли. вы завершили не основной поток, а поток который создает вложеный.  _Когда все основные потоки, принадлежащие процессу, завершились, общеязыковая среда выполнения завершает процесс. Все оставшиеся фоновые потоки останавливаются не закончив работу._ Цытата из MSDN. https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.threading.thread.isbackground(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: _"вы завершили не основной поток"_ -- основной поток приложения. то, что при завершении работы процесса, все остановится - понятно. просто из фразы _"Если задать потоку свойство IsBackground, то он автоматически завершиться"_ я решил, что в Thread добавили новую фичу.